# Canvas resolution and export resolution

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have canvas which is width="600px" and height="500px".

then I show the image(1200px and 1000px) on this canvas

```
ctx.drawImage(img,600,500);
```

finally export with this script.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = mycanvas.current.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.85);
```

In this case jpg's final resolution is 600px x 500px.

However I want to keep final resolution 1200 x 1000 jpg.

What is the best practice for this purpose.

Comment: Hello, through what I understood, that you want to display it (visually) in (600,500) and you want to export it in (1200,1000) ? if this is the case, I would recommend you to use a second hidden canvas, temporarely created, to save the state of 1200,1000 resolution and use it for exportation (you can do that by `document.createElement('canvas')`)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, that's what I want. but I was confused with clientWidth and width itselt.

Comment: there is no "width" property in JS Html Dom Elements, but there is : clientWidth, offsetWidth, scrollWidth .. if you want to know its differences, take a look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl1IA.png) it may help a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `clientWidth` and `width`

use `clientWidth = 600` and `width = 1200`

It can be done.

Answer (score 1):

## [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement)

### Resolution V Display Size

#### Resolution

To set the resolution (number of pixels) use the canvas element properties [HTMLCanvasElement.width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) and [HTMLCanvasElement.height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height)

- **Note** Setting [HTMLCanvasElement.width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) or [HTMLCanvasElement.height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height) will reset (clear / zero all pixels) setting [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) properties to default.

#### Display Size

To set the canvas elements display size (how big it is displayed on the page) use the element style (CSS) properties [HTMLCanvasElement.style.width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) and [HTMLCanvasElement.style.height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)

- **Note** that display pixels may not match the display devices` physical pixel size (size of pixels on the display). To know the physical pixel size use [devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio). The dimensions of physical pixels is currently unknown to browsers / JS.

### Example

Setting display size to half the resolution.

- **Note** that the [devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) must be used to adjust canvas pixels to page pixel size.

```
function resizeCanvas(canvasEl, width, height, displayScale = 0.5) {
    displayScale *= devicePixelRatio;
    canvasEl.width = width;
    canvasEl.height = height;
    canvasEl.style.width = (width * displayScale).toFixed(0) + "px";
    canvasEl.style.height = (height * displayScale).toFixed(0) + "px";
}
```

Using above function

```
// Set resolution 1200 by 1000 and display size 600 by 500. 
// Create dataURL of canvas image 1200 by 1000
const canvas = mycanvas.current;
resizeCanvas(canvas, 1200, 1000, 0.5); 
canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, canvas.width, canvas.height);
const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.85);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to keep your final resolution as 1200 x 1000 px.

```
var finalCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
finalCanvas.width = 1200;
finalCanvas.height = 1000;
var finalCtx = finalCanvas.getContext('2d');

finalCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, finalCanvas.width, finalCanvas.height);
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = finalCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.85);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!However this keeps the same size but I want to show this as half size.